# Is there a way to plot a non-circular arc in Bokeh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I am working on a flight path data visualization in Bokeh and am wondering if there is a more accurate way to plot the arcs.  Using great circle navigation equations between the two geolocations, I can find a midpoint, and I am currently using the arc glyph to plot a circle defined by the the points (start, mid, end) of the flight path, with the start and end angles being the locations of the two airports.

It works great for short routes, but very long routes that come near the poles get quite distorted, and the arcs don't look right.  This is due to the Web Mercator standard projection used in the CARTODBPOSITRON map by Bokeh.

I can also fid initial and final headings from the great circle nav equations.  So my fundamental question here is that I would like to do something like :

```
m = figure()
m.non_circular_arc(start_x, start_y, start_angle, mid_x, mid_y, end_x, end_y, end_angle)
```

Does anything of the sort exist in Bokeh?

Comment: Could you please post a sample output here? or demo desired results

Comment: Have a look at [_"How do great circles project on the mercator projection?_"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843444/how-do-great-circles-project-on-the-mercator-projection)

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh supports drawing cubic Bézier curves with the `bezier` glyph method:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.bezier

Or `quadratic` curves as well, if that is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2413223/467357) to [*"How do great circles project on the mercator projection?"*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1843444/467357) I had devised this Python function

```
def make_z(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    from math import degrees, radians, sin, sqrt
    from scipy.optimize import newton
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(radians, (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2))
    z1, z2 = map(sin, (lat1, lat2))
    def find_z2(lon0):
        dd = (1-z1**2)*sin(lon1+lon0)**2/z1**2
        s = sin(lon2+lon0)
        return z2-s/sqrt(dd+s**2)
    lon0 = newton(find_z2, 0)
    dd = (1-z1**2)*sin(lon1+lon0)**2/z1**2
    def z(f):
        s = sin(radians(f)+lon0)
        return s/sqrt(dd+s**2)
    return z
```

where the input is the quadruple (in degrees) that describe the
starting point and the end point of the great arc, and the output is a
function of the longitude (in degrees) that describes the normalized
(-1 < *z* < 1) height *z* on the map.

You use it like this

```
z = make_z(45, 10,   30, 100)
print(z(10), z(100))
# 0.7071067811865475 0.5000000000000003
```